# How to a copy file with versioning with cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

When you copy a file manually on Windows, it detects if there is a file of the same name and then proposes to version it. How to do this with the Windows command prompt and PowerShell?

I'd like to know if there is some Windows API I can call from PowerShell, not to do things from scratch.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tATBM.png)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: What about searching [SO] for present [batch](http://www.google.ocm/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+batch+copy+increment+number) or [powershell](http://www.google.ocm/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+powershell+copy+increment+number) solutions ?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how can you even try when you can't find any parameter mentionned anywhere to do so ?

Comment: Windows wraps the logic in the GUI.  What you're asking is basically "how can I mimic the GUI"?  It's pretty simple to do in PowerShell if you spend 5 minutes thinking about it.

Comment: I doubt it is simple because in some past I have already tried to do it in C# and it's not so simple as for calculating the next version depending on the file name scheme.

Comment: Normally Windows has an API and it is possible it is part of it except it's a labyrinth to know where it is.

Comment: The question isn't new. It **is** answered several times at least once in both categories by me and you didn't show any effort in research or own coding what is expected in a programmers site.

Comment: It *is* simple.  You check whether a version exists (index into the substring), and +1 it.

Comment: No, there is no built in magic way to do this in PowerShell that I am aware of. You would need to build the naming and collision logic yourself. Adding a number suffix is not terribly difficult. If you are having issues show us what you tried and we can help with that specific issue.

Comment: @Matt at first glance it's simple, as I said I tried to do so in the past. The beast is in the details. I can't find my old c# script because it's a long time ago but I did give up when realizing it's too farfetched to get it right in every little case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Google search for "copy replace gui powershell" presented this as second option

Found at http://blog.backslasher.net/copying-files-in-powershell-using-windows-explorer-ui.html

```
function Copy-ItemUsingExplorer{
    param(
        [string]$source,
        [string]$destination,
        [int]$CopyFlags
    )

    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'    
    $objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace((gi $destination).FullName)
    $objFolder.CopyHere((gi $source).FullName,$CopyFlags.ToString('{0:x}'))
}


Copy-ItemUsingExplorer -source C:\Users\Default\Desktop\End -destination C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Start
```

Comment: Does this handle name collisions automatically?

Comment: I think with CopyFlags 8. But i could be wrong

Comment: According to [CopyHere docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you would be right assuming this works for individual files as well.

Comment: @ArcSet thanks will try. Cannot upvote since I'm new here.

Comment: @Arset I don't want to copy a whole folder but only a specific file, CopyHere does seem to only work with folder ?

Comment: CopyHere works with files.

`Copy-ItemUsingExplorer -source C:\Users\Default\Desktop\End\test.txt -destination C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Start`